# How to start Splunk Forwarder within a script

Tags: docker, dockerfile, splunk

I would like to start to monitor our dockers with Splunk. To do it I want to add it to the docker buildfile.

The issue is that if its the first time you start the forwarder, it prompts you to agree for the license agreement, which breaks the script.

Is there a way to start the Splunk forwarder without being prompted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments you are looking for are `--accept-license --answer-yes --no-prompt`.

A Splunk employee publishes some [Docker images](https://github.com/outcoldman/docker-splunk) on his own time that can cater for this already. Have a look at `SPLUNK_START_ARGS` in the forwarders [`entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/outcoldman/docker-splunk/tree/master/universalforwarder).

Also, Docker natively [supports sending its own logs to Splunk](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/splunk/). This includes the stdout and stderr of all containers so you may not need your own forwarder.

Comment: That is super useful. Where can I find the values for: splunk-token, splunk-capath, splunk-caname? We are using splunk cloud light.

Comment: The token can be generated by you in the Web UI for the *HTTP Event Collector* once you have enabled it. I'm not sure if that is part of splunk cloud light, check with their support.

Comment: The `caname` will default to your url, you shouldn't need it. The root certificate for `capath` for a splunk cloud instance should be downloadable somewhere, support should be able to give you a link. You could use `splunk-insecureskipverify` for testing to skip the TLS verification.

Comment: If you have hundreds or thousands of servers this may help.

https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/splunk-forwarder-installation-using-ansible/